# Getting error after inserting 3 pages php data insert script

Tags: php

I have 3 php pages where details is supposed to be inserted to db in final php.. I am geetting these warnings below however data is inserted. I know these warning can be turned of by error reporting but doesnt look good to me go for that..

```
Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/opterfhb/public_html/quest4home.com/search/add_edit_property_finish.php on line 301

Warning: unlink(tmp_imgs/tmp_1011/..): Is a directory in /home/opterfhb/public_html/quest4home.com/search/add_edit_property_finish.php on line 302

Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/opterfhb/public_html/quest4home.com/search/add_edit_property_finish.php on line 301

Warning: unlink(tmp_imgs/tmp_1011/.): Is a directory in /home/opterfhb/public_html/quest4home.com/search/add_edit_property_finish.php on line 302
```

I think I have defined it wrong way.. seeking help..

I am getting error on this section:

```
// Moveing temp images to property directory
if ($handle = opendir('tmp_imgs/tmp_'.$property_id)) {      
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
//$file_ext = strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1));

copy('tmp_imgs/tmp_'.$property_id.'/'.$file, 'property_images/img_'.$property_id.'/'.$file);
unlink('tmp_imgs/tmp_'.$property_id.'/'.$file);
}
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: error seems clear to me **The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory**

Comment: @Dagon Thanks.. I just updated the $file description..

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit is 1000% correct its **.** and **..**

Comment: have more more 0's @Karlos, look at example 2 of the manual for [readdir()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Comment: Thanks @Dagaon.. Going through it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear: you cannot use that function to copy directories. However, you may not be aware that you're even trying to do this in the first place.

There are magical "files" in each directory which are themselves directories (`.` and `..`), so if you're iterating over a directory and copying everything in it, you need to explicitly skip those two.